# If $R$ and $R^{-1}$ are well orderings on some set S, then S is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have been studying set theory of Herbert Enderton as I came about this problem in exercise section in chapter about ordinals. I have tried proving this using least upper bounds, pigeonhole principle, isomorphisms and as well tried proving by showing that S can be made of finite union of finite sets, but all failed.

Of course it is possible that I missed something on those tries, lest have been unsuccessful.

I prefer hints over full proof, but full proof is very much welcome as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** If $S$ is an infinite set and $R$ is a well-ordering on $S$, then $R$ has an initial segment isomorphic to $\omega$.

---

If $S$ is infinite, note that $R$ has an initial segment of order type $\omega$, therefore this is an infinite decreasing sequence in $R^{-1}$, so it is not a well-order.

Incidentally, the axiom of choice is equivalent to the following statement: $S$ is finite if and only if whenever $R$ is a well-ordering of $S$ then $R^{-1}$ is a well-ordering of $S$.

The proof is so simple, you'd feel cheated: If the axiom of choice holds, then the above shows why this is true; if the axiom of choice fails then there is a set $S$ which cannot be well-ordered (and so necessarily infinite), and vacuously every well-ordering of $S$, $R$, satisfies that $R^{-1}$ is a well-ordering of $S$.

Comment: Think I got it, please furnish the full proof to complete the question. Thank you